# 2 encodings between an HTML representation

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, w3c

Im reading one chapter from the W3C [HTML Document Representation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html)

In the [5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html#doc-char-set) says this:

User agents must also know the specific character encoding that was used to transform the document character stream into a byte stream.

Then in the [5.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html#encodings) says this:

The "charset" parameter identifies a character encoding, which is a method of converting a sequence of bytes into a sequence of characters.

Char-Bytes

Bytes-Char

So im wrong or there are 2 encodings between the representation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "character encoding" such as UTF-8 is, strictly speaking, a specification for representing characters as a sequence of bytes.  But the encodings are always reversible, so we can speak of a (single) character encoding as going both ways.

Other character encodings used in practice are UTF-16 ad UTF-32.

Each of these are specifications under which you can encode text as bytes and decode bytes into characters.  Two parts of the same specification.

Comment: So to store the chars it have to be encoded, and when is represented , for instance, the charset=UTF-8 in a meta tag, decode those bytes that has been encoded by the text editor etc?

Comment: Yes.  When you store a text document in a file, you have to tell your text editor what encoding to use when it saves the file.  The file is stored as a byte sequence.  When a web server sends this file to someone's browser, it sends the byte stream.  You should send the encoding used inside an HTTP response header, or ensure your HTML document has a <meta> tag that says which encoding was used.  The user's browser will use this information to decode the byte stream into characters for display.